# How to save raspi data from the SD Card

Tags: sd-card, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, computer-vision

I recently installed the computer-vision-related libraries on my Raspberry Pi 4 running [os-bullseye]. However, I cannot log in to the system after the installation.

**Issue Description:**

- While logIn shows " A problem occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."

**Steps Taken:**

- I installed the pytorch-related dependencies to run my computer-vision model for inference on raspberry pi 4.

**Hardware and Software Details:**

- Raspberry Pi 4 model B.
- Raspbian-os-bullseye.

**What I've Tried:**

- I have tried Ext2Read for saving data from SD Card but couldn't able to do it.

**Goal:**

- To save my data from the SD Card, OR
- Able to Log In to my system.

I appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: `I have tried Ext2Read for saving data from SD Card but couldn't able to do it.` - what happened when you tried? How did you try?

Comment: While running Ext2Read on my system, a pop-up window stating "unable to read the disk" is showing although I'm running the application as an administrator.

Comment: do you have a USB thumb drive? You can boot from that in the pi (after imaging it of course) then plug in the SD card (after the pi has booted from the USB drive), and recover your data, or maybe even fix the issue, from there